# Проверка на неверные символы в json-тексте

Tags: python, python-3.x, командная-строка

Вопрос, наверное, очень глупый, но результат у меня выходит не тот, что мне нужен, поэтому все же спрошу: 
У меня есть json'овский текст с адресами неких сайтов, которые мне нужно вывести в терминал (только адреса). Это получилось. Но мне нужно также выводить следом за ними еще и ошибку, мол, "Невозможно вывести результат запроса" в том случае, если в строке текста есть неверные символы, например, не обычные кавычки, а типографские. И вот здесь у меня никак не получается вывести все это вместе (это не первый вариант того, что я пытался запихнуть в код в качестве проверки, но там оже все было не лучше (в основном просто не выводило ничего).. Ниже прикреплю сам файл и питоновский код. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь и, если не сложно, объяснение, ибо только учусь. Заранее спасибо.

Код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-*-coding: utf-8-*-
import sys 
import argparse
import json
from json import loads
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c", "--Column", type=int, help="Номер колонки") 
parser.add_argument("-k", "--Key", help="Ключ для поиска") 
parser.add_argument("-f", "--File", help="Имя файла") 
args=parser.parse_args()
f=sys.stdin 
try:
    f=open(sys.argv[6])
except IndexError:
    print("Выполнение через конвейер")
finally:
    for line in f:
        c=line.split("\t")
        n=int(args.Column)
        if len(c)>=n:
            try:
                json=loads(c[n-1])
            except:
                print("Невозможно вывести результат запроса")
                if args.Key in json.keys(): 
                    print(json[args.Key])
```

Сам файл с json-текстом:

```
example.com {"ttl":300,"addr":"127.0.0.1","type":"A","class":"IN"}
xyz.com {"ttl":1200,"addr":"24.36.127.15","type":"A","class":"IN"}
supermail.tw    {"ttl":600,"addr":"62.77.109.93","type":"A","class":"IN"}
alison.som  {"ttl”:1800,“addr”:“66.54.119.97”,“type”:“A”,“class”:“IN”}
```

Последняя сточка содержит неправильные символы (конкретно: типографские кавычки).

Результат в терминале:

```
./2.py -c 2 -k addr -f address.json
Невозможно вывести результат запроса
62.77.109.93
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Строка с типографскими кавычками не парсится в `loads`, т.к. такие кавычки не соответствуют формату json

Comment: Я понимаю. Мне и нужно, чтобы файл проверялся на такие кавычки и выводил результат в тех строках, где все нормально, а вместо строки с этими кавычками выводил какую-то ошибку/предупреждение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы это имели ввиду?

```
...

try:
    f = open(sys.argv[6])
except IndexError:
    print("Выполнение через конвейер")
finally:
    for line in f:
        c = line.split("\t")
        n = int(args.Column)
        if len(c) >= n:
            data = c[n-1]
            try:
                json = loads(data)
                if args.Key in json:
                    print(json[args.Key])
            except:
                print("Невозможно вывести результат запроса. Невалидный json:", data)
```

Comment: Да! Огромное вам спасибо за помощь! Именно это мне и нужно было.